# Problem with multiple SQL queries in promise chain in NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise, load-data-infile

I have the following code that runs once a day and first deletes all records from a table and then inserts a new set of records, using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`.

```
promisemysql.createConnection(currentDB)
            .then(function(conn) {
                var result = conn.query(returnQueries.returnQueries('deleteSuppliers'));
                conn.end();

                return;
            })
            .then(function() {
                promisemysql.createConnection(currentDB)
                    .then(function(conn) {
                        var result = conn.query(returnQueries.returnQueries('loadSuppliers'));
                        conn.end();
                        console.log("Suppliers database updated.");

                        return;
                    });
            });
```

The query is `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/SuppliersCSV.csv' INTO TABLE Suppliers FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (supplierCode, supplier) SET id = NULL;`

The problem is the code works just fine on a test VM with Ubuntu 18.04, NodeJS 12 and MySQL 5.7.29 while on another VM with the same configuration has a totally different behavior.

On the first run, it deletes all data from the table but fails to insert anything. On the second run, it inserts all data. On the third will delete the data without inserting, and so on...

The weird part is that I used the exact same code but with a different query (a huge INSERT instead of LOAD DATA LOCAL FILE) and it worked on both VMs.

I've been trying to figure it out for quite some time now, without any luck so far and I'm running out of ideas.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What does `conn.query()` return - is it Promise?

Comment: If not, then use mysql-promise